# Relative module was not found, but all modules are there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I am migrating a react app to using typescript and suddenly I am getting this error.

```
This relative module was not found:

* ./ in ./src/app/redux/reducers.ts
```

The file in question is the following:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import attachments from "./Attachments/reducer";
import announcements from "./Announcements/reducer";
import lectures from "./Lectures/reducer";
import lectureBlockResources from "./LectureBlockResources/reducer";
import chapters from "./Chapters/reducer";
import teaching from "./Teaching/reducer";
import invitations from "./Invitations/reducer";
import settings from "./settings/reducer";
import meetings from "./Meetings/reducer";
import categories from "./Categories/reducer";
import instructors from "./Instructors/reducer";
import groups from "./Groups/reducer";
import groupUsers from "./GroupUsers/reducer";
import groupCourses from "./GroupCourses/reducer";
import reviews from "./Reviews/reducer";
import auth from "./Auth/reducer";
import company from "./Company/reducer";
import companyPersonalizations from "./CompanyPersonalizations/reducer";
import profile from "./Profile/reducer";
import course from "./Course/reducer";
import objectives from "./Objectives/reducer";
import requirements from "./Requirements/reducer";
import users from "./users/reducer";
import userCourses from "./userCourses/reducer";
import userNotes from "./userNotes/reducer";
import students from "./Students/reducer";
import theme from "./Themes/reducer";
import courseProgram from "./CourseProgram/reducer";
import certificates from "./Certificates/reducer";
import tests from "./Test/reducer";
import evaluations from "./Evaluations/reducer";
import tour from "./Tour/reducer";
import userCalifications from "./UserCalification/reducer";
import courseSurveys from "./CourseSurvey/reducer";

const appReducer = combineReducers({
    attachments,
    announcements,
    lectures,
    chapters,
    teaching,
    invitations,
    settings,
    meetings,
    categories,
    instructors,
    company,
    companyPersonalizations,
    objectives,
    requirements,
    reviews,
    auth,
    course,
    profile,
    users,
    userCourses,
    userNotes,
    students,
    groups,
    groupUsers,
    theme,
    groupCourses,
    courseProgram,
    certificates,
    tests,
    evaluations,
    lectureBlockResources,
    tour,
    userCalifications,
    courseSurveys
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === "AUTH_CLEAN") {
        state = undefined;
    }
    return appReducer(state, action);
};

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("./", () => {
        const nextRootReducer = rootReducer;
        store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
}

export default rootReducer;
```

I've never encountered this before and I have no idea where to follow. Has anyone had the experience of knowing what causes missing module errors from happening when they are not supposed to?

Comment: Maybe your new setup is case sensitive, but your old setup wasn't? E.g. maybe `"./settings/reducer";` should be `"./Settings/reducer";`, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel kinda stupid. Essentially when I started renaming files I renamed the reducer file from index.js to reducers.ts

That essentially broke the hot reloading setting we had, since the renaming needed to happen there as well:

This:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("./", () => {
        const nextRootReducer = rootReducer;
        store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
}
```

Had to change to this:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept("./reducers", () => {
        const nextRootReducer = rootReducer;
        store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
}
```

Or essentially, whatever the file was named.